# How to get the r path in Chromebook for setup on vs code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I tried running a **R program** on my vs code installed on my Chromebook, but I can't do that, I keep getting the message to set up my r path. I should change it from **r.rterm.linux** **to r path**. I don't know where to find the path directory on Chromebook.
Please someone should help me out or give me an alternative to run a R program on Chromebook.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd>) and run this command:

```bash
which R
```

It should print your R path.